# Change for-loop to while loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

How to change the  for-loop to a while loop?

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == k) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }

        }
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Algorithmus {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Geben sie den gesuchten Wert ein: ");
        int k = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Geben sie die Länge des Arrays ein: ");
        int n = s.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println("Geben sie die Werte ein:");
        for(i = 0;i<n;i++){
            arr[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        boolean found = false;
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == k) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (found==true) {
            System.out.println((i+1));
        } else {
            System.out.println((arr.length + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

The structure should be:

```
BEGIN
Input: k1, ..., kn, k;
found := FALSE;
WHILE NOT found AND „not all elements were viewed“ DO
„take the next element ki“;
found := (ki = k)
END (* WHILE *);
IF found THEN
Output: i
ELSE
OUtput: n + 1
END (* IF *)
END
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Algorithmus  {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Geben sie den gesuchten Wert ein: ");
            int k = s.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Geben sie die Länge des Arrays ein: ");
            int n = s.nextInt();
            int arr[] = new int[n];
            int i = 0;
            System.out.println("Geben sie die Werte ein:");
            for(i = 0;i<n;i++){
                arr[i] = s.nextInt();
            }
            boolean found = false;
            i=0;
            while (i < arr.length) {

                if (arr[i] == k) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            i++;

            }


            if (found==true) {
                System.out.println((i+1));
            } else {
                System.out.println((arr.length + 1));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This one is working, i  think i know my fault. I deleted i=0; all the time bc i thought it was declared already. Now i just need to change the the if-output is i and not i+1 i forgot to explain it in my question.

Comment: The code is working now just fine. I just had to add i++; in if(found) and print out i and now i get the result with the structure. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Something equivalent would be:

```
int i = 0;

while (i < arr.length) {
    if (arr[i] == k) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```java
int idx = 0;
while(idx < arr.length && a[idx] != k) {
    idx++
}

if(idx == arr.length) {
    // element not found, do something
} else {
    // element found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int i = 0;
while(arr.length > i){
//code
++i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
int i=0;
while (i < arr.length) {
    if (arr[i] == k) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: what are you program implementing for?

Comment: The while-loop is part of the code and should work in context with the code.